# Can I set PowerShell 'Start-Job' with low priority?

Tags: powershell, start-job

I would like to lower the priority of the jobs that I start with [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6) in PowerShell scripts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used this trick right in a job's code (it can be optional, controlled by a parameter):

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.Priority = 'Lowest'
```

Available priority values: Lowest, BelowNormal, Normal, AboveNormal, Highest

Answer (score 7):

If you have launched it then you can use this:

```
 $a = gps powershell
 $a.PriorityClass = "BelowNormal"
```

Or you can use this using the key:

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_process -filter 'name = "notepad.exe"' | foreach-object { $_.SetPriority(32) }
```

The priority codes are as follows:

```
 256 REALTIME
 128 HIGH_PRIORITY
 32768 ABOVE_NORMAL
 32 NORMAL
 16384 BELOW_NORMAL
 64 IDLE
```