# How to run batch "Start" from powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, start-process

In a Powershell script I would like to launch a process (a java program) using the batch "Start" command. The reason for using this is that I would like to have control over process priority as well as the CPU numa node and affinity assignment, and the only way I have found to do that is through batch "Start" (https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

As an example, in Powershell I can run

```
cmd /c myprocess
```

without problems, but running

```
start /AboveNormal "windowname" myprocess
```

I get the error "Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ... ". Running from a batch script it runs fine.

It looks to me like Powershell is trying to execute the command using the native "Start-Process", but I am not sure how to overwrite that. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `cmd /c start /AboveNormal "windowname" myprocess`?

Comment: Then I get the error "cmd : The system cannot find the file windowname.". However, if I then remove "windowname" and run `cmd /c start /AboveNormal myprocess` it actually works. I'm not sure how, as the window title is a required argument for start (at least in batch scripting), but that is not so important I guess.

Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: I am not that big of a Powershell user but just searching StackOverFlow I see a lot of Powershell answers for this question already.

Comment: You're using PowerShell and under that, `Start` is an alias of `Start-Process`, if you take a look at the usage information for Start-Process, i.e. `Get-Help Start-Process -Detailed`, you'll find out all you should need. I might suggest something along the lines of `Start-Process -FilePath "$Env:ComSpec" -ArgumentList "/C Start \`"Window Title\`" /AboveNormal \`"C:\Users\Hove\My Directory\MyProcess.exe\`""`.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use Windows command processor to start a Java application with a process priority above normal. PowerShell is much more powerful than Windows command processor and it is of course also possible with PowerShell to do that. Look for example on [Can I set PowerShell 'Start-Job' with low priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995767/) and the link posted in question. Even better is [in PowerShell, set affinity in start-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250927/).

Comment: The documentations needed are [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) and [ProcessStartInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) and in this case additionally [ProcessPriorityClass Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processpriorityclass). Reading all __Process__ related documentations would be even better to get better knowledge on process management by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`start` is a `cmd` command, so launch it via `cmd`, just remember to escape quotes:

```
cmd /c "start ""windowname"" myprocess"
# or
cmd /c "start `"windowname`" myprocess"
```